# Regarding the conversion of hostnames to ip address

Tags: dns

Can two or more domains be hosted on the same server? If yes what is the ip address we are going to get for the two domains?

as a user can i know how a server resolves the host name and assign unique id to different host names

Comment: in DNS terminology, a domain is just a name.  Perhaps you want to say a zone (a common administrative group of domains to be administered as a whole).  Commonly, all servers allow you to administer several zones in one server.... many allow you even to answer different *views* depending on client location.  Try ISC bind and buy a good book on DNS.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my comment above and as you are a user, not an administrator, just look at the documentation of **nslookup(1)**.  It is a tool to make DNS queries to servers.  It allow you to make dns resolution and to investigate the ways you are getting the answer (there are many ways to answer a query, believe me)

First you need to know how the asking is being done.  Normally, clients make recursive queries (they want definitive answers to a query and want the server to do the heavy work) and servers do iterative ones (they approximate the answer by asking the servers in the chain to the final domain you are looking for)  Servers and clients normally cache results for future questions and provide several ways of fault tolerance, so you cannot control normally how a query is solved.  As this is probably the most requested service in internet, the protocol has been optimized to get quick answers even in the worst case.

Once you get an answer, it can be a partial one, it can be cached, it can be non-authoritative (meaning the server is serving a cached entry, not a locally administered one)

When you have several responses to a query (ok, this can happen) you receive them normally in order, depending where are you querying from. The server makes a best effort to order them on proximity to the client (the nearest address is served first) and/or randomly ordered, so you can make round robing to each of the addresses you receive.  It depends on the client software, the server implementation, the administrator policy, etc.

Even you can receive a different response depending on who you are.  Several corporate servers serve different views of the database depending on where the clients come from.  If they come from the inside of the company, they serve addresses for servers not visible from the outside.  For example, if you try to access the corporate web server, you can receive the private address to reach it, not the public address of the server accesible from the internet.  This concept is called view, and many servers implement it, so the answer to your question is: it depends :)

Comment: Please use `dig` instead of `nslookup`.

Comment: Sorry, I was educated the old way :)

Comment: But your comment is welcome, as it documents further the response.  Thanks!